# Default values for empty groups in Linq GroupBy query

Tags: linq, grouping, default-value

I have a data set of values that I want to summarise in groups. For each group, I want to create an array big enough to contain the values of the largest group. When a group contains less than this maximum number, I want to insert a default value of zero for the empty key values.

**Dataset**

```
Col1    Col2    Value
--------------------
A       X       10
A       Z       15
B       X       9
B       Y       12
B       Z       6
```

**Desired result**

```
X, [10, 9]
Y, [0, 12]
Z, [15, 6]
```

Note that value "A" in Col1 in the dataset has no value for "Y" in Col2. Value "A" is first group in the outer series, therefore it is the first element that is missing.

The following query creates the result dataset, but does not insert the default zero values for the Y group.

```
result = data.GroupBy(item => item.Col2)
             .Select(group => new
             {
                 name = group.Key,
                 data = group.Select(item => item.Value)
                             .ToArray()
             })
```

**Actual result**

```
X, [10, 9]
Y, [12]
Z, [15, 6]
```

What do I need to do to insert a zero as the missing group value?

Comment: You could put it in an OLEDB datatable and not do "ToArray" already in the first step. Then on datatable you could define what to do fill for null values and then bring this back to array.

Comment: What's the rule that makes the desired result for `Y` to be `[0, 12]` and not `[12, 0]`?

Comment: Is the data in memory or in a database?

Comment: I think you didn't formulate the question correctly. From what I see, it looks like you are trying to do is a so called fixed cross tab query, with Col2 being a row grouping and Col1 being a column grouping. Is that correct?

Comment: @IvanStoev Good point. It has to do with the order of the outer group. Value "A" in Col1 has no value for "Y" in Col2. Value "A" is first group in the outer series, so it is the first element that is missing. Will update question.

Comment: @YacoubMassad it can be either. Think of it as an `IEnumerable<dynamic>`. The question is how to write the LINQ query.

Comment: @IvanStoev that's more or less right yes. The data is being prepared for a chart object. The outer series represents x-axis categories, the inner series is a subgroup within those categores.

Comment: Is the maximum size of the array always 2?

Comment: @YacoubMassad no, it there is  no limit.

Comment: Can you provide an example (sample data) where you have A,B, and C? I guess in this case, the maximum number in the array would be 3, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how I understand it.

Let say we have this

```
class Data
{
    public string Col1, Col2;
    public decimal Value;
}

Data[] source =
{
    new Data { Col1="A", Col2 = "X", Value = 10 },
    new Data { Col1="A", Col2 = "Z", Value = 15 },
    new Data { Col1="B", Col2 = "X", Value = 9 },
    new Data { Col1="B", Col2 = "Y", Value = 12 },
    new Data { Col1="B", Col2 = "Z", Value = 6 },
};
```

First we need to determine the "fixed" part

```
var columns = source.Select(e => e.Col1).Distinct().OrderBy(c => c).ToList();
```

Then we can process with the normal grouping, but inside the group we will  **left join** the `columns` with group elements which will allow us to achieve the desired behavior

```
var result = source.GroupBy(e => e.Col2, (key, elements) => new
{
    Key = key,
    Elements = (from c in columns
             join e in elements on c equals e.Col1 into g
             from e in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select e != null ? e.Value : 0).ToList()
})
.OrderBy(e => e.Key)
.ToList();
```

Comment: Nice one! Is that a LINQ crosstab query btw? I take it the `select e != null ? e.Value : 0` expression is what makes it a left join?

Comment: Not really. As you see it's not a single LINQ query. If you mean the element extension part, I guess it's simple a left join concept to allow including missing matching items from the `right` side of the join.

Comment: That was for the crosstab. And yes, the combination of `DefaultIfEmpty` plus the null check compose the so called `left outer join`

Answer (score 2):

It won't be pretty, but you can do something like this:

```
var groups = data.GroupBy(d => d.Col2, d => d.Value)
                 .Select(g => new { g, count = g.Count() })
                 .ToList();
int maxG = groups.Max(p => p.count);
var paddedGroups = groups.Select(p => new {
                     name = p.g.Key,
                     data = p.g.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(0, maxG - p.count)).ToArray() });
```

Comment: Would you really want to group the data by the Value field? That would just produce the same dataset without Col1 and sorted by Col2 I think.

Comment: @PaulTaylor this is not grouping by the value filed. The second lambda in the GroupBy lets you choose the resulting value, so the result of that method call is a `IGrouping<string,int>` instead of a `IGrouping<string,Data>` which removes the need of a later `Select(item => item.Value)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:-

```
int maxCount = 0;
var result = data.GroupBy(x => x.Col2)
             .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count())
             .Select(x => 
                {
                   if (maxCount == 0)
                       maxCount = x.Count();
                   var Value = x.Select(z => z.Value);
                   return new 
                   {
                      name = x.Key,
                      data = maxCount == x.Count() ? Value.ToArray() : 
                                 Value.Concat(new int[maxCount - Value.Count()]).ToArray()
                   };
                });
```

**Code Explanation**:-

Since you need to append `default zeros` in case when you have less items in any group, I am storing the maxCount (which any group can produce in a variable `maxCount`) for this I am ordering the items in descending order. Next I am storing the maximum count which the item can producr in `maxCount` variable. While projecting I am simply checking if number of items in the group is not equal to `maxCount` then create an `integer array` of size (maxCount - x.Count) i.e. maximum count minus number of items in current group and appending it to the array.

[**Working Fiddle.**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qZrnoX)