# LINQ Create a nested List

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am trying to convert a flat list to nested list.

**This is my flat list:**

```
public class DefectLocationCount {
    public string LocationName { get; set; }
    public string DefectName { get; set; }
    public int TotalCount { get; set; }
}
```

**This is my nested list:**

```
public class DefectLocationOutput
{
    public string DefectName{ get; set; }
    public List<int> TotalCount{ get; set; }
}
```

**This is my linq query to populate the flat list**

```
var results = (from def in rep.tblDefects
               join defLoc in 
                  (from defDet in rep.tblMovementDefects
                     join det in rep.tblMovementDetails on defDet.MovementDetailId equals det.MovementDetailId
                     join loc in rep.tblLocations on det.ToLocationId equals loc.LocationId
                     join hed in rep.tblMovementHeaders on det.MovementHeaderId equals hed.MovemenHeaderId
                     where hed.DateCreated >= fromDate && hed.DateCreated <= toDate
                     select new { loc.LocationName, defDet.DefectId, loc.LocationId }
                   ) on def.DefectId equals defLoc.DefectId
                   group def by new { def.DefectName, defLoc.LocationId, defLoc.LocationName } into joined
                   select new
                   {
                       LocationName = joined.Key.LocationName,
                       LocationId = joined.Key.LocationId,
                       DefectName = joined.Key.DefectName,
                       TotalCount = joined.Count()
                    }).OrderBy(x => x.LocationId);
```

**Edit**

**This is what i am trying to achieve**
[image]
In the format of `List<DefectLocationOutput>` and instead of `null` values have `0`.

**How can this be done?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't really understand what result are you awaiting, but maybe this will help you:

```
DefectLocationCount cl1 = new DefectLocationCount()
            {
                DefectName = "Name1",
                LocationName = "Location1",
                TotalCount = 2
            };

DefectLocationCount cl2 = new DefectLocationCount()
            {
                DefectName = "Name1",
                LocationName = "Location2",
                TotalCount = 3
            };

DefectLocationCount cl3 = new DefectLocationCount()
            {
                DefectName = "Name2",
                LocationName = "Location3",
                TotalCount = 6
            };

var lstCl = new List<DefectLocationCount>();
lstCl.Add(cl1);
lstCl.Add(cl2);
lstCl.Add(cl3);

var result = lstCl.GroupBy(x => x.DefectName).Select(x => new DefectLocationOutput() { DefectName = x.Key, TotalCount = lstCl.Where(y => y.DefectName == x.Key).Select(y => y.TotalCount).ToList() });
```

Comment: Hi Julia, could you change your solution to my edit. The results from your solution are correct except they are scattered and the locations with 0 defect count are not part of the output list, which is my current objective.

Comment: I found an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34334911/default-values-for-empty-groups-in-linq-groupby-query. It gave me the result as my edit indicates